# DNN Real-time Shipping Rates won't pull UPS rates

Tags: dotnetnuke, rate, ups

I am running DNN 7.4.1. I was having some issues with the accuracy of real-time calculations from UPS, but they were pulling from UPS. I briefly switched the Freight Charges Type in the Store Settings to use Freight Weight calculations. This did not work for my purposes, so I switched it back to the Real-time rate calculations, but it will no longer pull the rates from UPS as it did before. No other settings have changed to my knowledge. All the UPS web service settings in the store settings are the same as they were previously. The only shipping rate that it shows now is the custom shipping rate that I have set up in the Shipping Rates Module. I am new to DNN, so any help would be much appreciated. Thanks [Screen shot: Shipping Calculator not showing UPS Rates](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QC1lI.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found in the DNN Event Log that I was getting error responses from the UPS API saying that the UPS Access Key and Password were missing. I am assuming that DNN cleared those two fields from the store settings for security reasons when I switched to use the Freight Weight calculations. Once I added back the Access Key and Password it began pulling the UPS rates as normal. I incorrectly assumed that all the settings were the same since I hadn't touched them.